# ¿Por qué en este ejemplo no funciona la sobre escritura de métodos?

Tags: c#, polimorfismo

Tengo una duda, en este ejemplo tengo 3 clases:

1. Clase base que tiene un método imprimir.
2. Clase padre que hereda de clase base e implementa el método imprimir.
3. Clase hija que hereda de clase padre e implementa el método imprimir.

Según tengo entendido es que si yo guardo todos estos objetos en una referencia de tipo clase base, cada vez que yo ejecute el método imprimir, cada objeto entrara a su sobre escritura del método imprimir, pero al hacer este ejemplo, todos entran al método de la clase base e imprimen `Clase Base` en vez de escribir `Clase Base, Clase padre, Clase hija`.

¿Alguien que me pueda explicar por qué no se sobrescribe?, ¿por qué no funciona el polimorfismo ahí?:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<ClassBase>()
            {
                new ClassBase()
                new ClassHija(),
                new ClassPadre(),
            };

            list.ForEach(x => x.Imprimir());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }


    public class ClassBase
    {
        public void Imprimir()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clase Base");
        }
    }

    public class ClassPadre : ClassBase
    {
        public void Imprimir()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clase Padre");
        }
    }

    public class ClassHija : ClassPadre
    {
        public void Imprimir()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clase Hija");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas declarar **explícitamente** que has sobrescrito el método. Para esto usas el modificador [override](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override)

Además, solo es posible modificar un método, propiedad, indexador o evento heredado si es que ha sido definido como `virtual` o `abstract`

En otras palabras

- El elemento ha modificar debe ser `virtual` o `abstract`
- El nuevo elemento (el modificado) debe ser `override`

```
public class ClassBase
{
    public virtual void Imprimir() //<- VIRTUAL en la clase base
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clase Base");
    }
}

public class ClassPadre : ClassBase
{
    public override void Imprimir() //<- OVERRIDE para REEMPLAZAR al método padre

    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clase Padre");
    }
}

public class ClassHija : ClassPadre
{
    public override void Imprimir() //<- OVERRIDE para REEMPLAZAR al método padre
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clase Hija");
    }
}
```

---

Update: Para responder el comentario:

> pero por ejemplo porque si el objeto es de tipo hijo el compilador no
> toma el metodo del hijo? solo si le pongo override o literalmente hago
> una referencia del hijo con Hijo hijo = new Hijo() y porque no
> funciona asi Base hijo = new Hijo();

Es la esencia del polimorfismo, un objeto puede tener muchas formas y en cada forma comportarse diferente

Por ejemplo, NO usamos `override`, es decir tenemos las clases como originalmente están en la pregunta

```
ClassHija hija = new ClassHija();
hija.Imprimir(); // Clase Hija
(hija as ClassPadre).Imprimir(); //Clase Padre
(hija as ClassBase).Imprimir(); //Clase Base
```

El mismo objeto llama a métodos distintos según sea su forma (el tipo), es decir cuando es `ClassHija` llamará a imprimir "Clase Hija", cuando es `ClassPadre` imprimirá "Clase Padre" y si es `ClassBase` "Clase Base"

Pueden existir algunos casos de usos para este comportamiento (en la práctica no se me ocurre ninguno), lo habitual en mi experiencia es que no nos interese la forma, nosotros queremos que el objeto se comporte tal y como es originalmente, es decir como fue instanciado y es ahí que usamos `override`

Mismo ejemplo, pero ahora los métodos de las clases usan `override` tal y como lo tengo yo arriba en mi respuesta

```
ClassHija hija = new ClassHija();
hija.Imprimir(); // Clase Hija
(hija as ClassPadre).Imprimir(); // Clase Hija
(hija as ClassBase).Imprimir(); // Clase Hija
```

Ahora en todos los caso se imprime "Clase Hija"

Entonces tenemos 2 comportamientos distintos para casos de usos distintos, y gracias a los modificadores `override` y `virtual` podemos elegir cual usar en nuestro caso

Comment: pero por ejemplo porque si el objeto es de tipo hijo el compilador no toma el metodo del hijo? solo si le pongo override o literalmente hago una referencia del hijo con `Hijo hijo = new Hijo()` y porque no funciona asi  `Base hijo = new Hijo()`

Comment: @LuisGarcia `ClassHija` es también `ClassPadre` y `ClassBase` y esa es la esencia misma del polimorfismo, tienes un elemento que posee muchas formas.  `ClassHija`  tiene los métodos de su padre y abuelo, en tu código tienes 3 métodos que se llamarán según la forma que estes usando (el tipo).  Ahora tu no quieres ese comportamiento, tu quieres que sin importar la forma se llame al evento que corresponde según su instanciación, entonces ahí aplicas `override`